# Log in to Dropbox with known credentials in Java

Tags: java, oauth, dropbox-api

I'm developing a Java application that uses dropbox APIs. I need my Java app to use a specific Dropbox user for which I already have credentials, so I do not have to ask for authentication to the user, but the user is uploading the files in my dropbox space.

Is there a way to get the auth token without having to open the login window?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [official dropbox sdk for java](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java#overview)

And there is an [example for authorization](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/authorize)

Comment: I badly explained myself. I do not need every user to access their dropbox space, but that all users in my application access my dropbox space and can upload and download their own files from my space.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution. In the official dropbox forum, I found this post. I hope it can be useful.

https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Login-without-DB-UI-intervention/m-p/132663/highlight/true#M3924

Comment: That's correct, it is technically possible to store and re-use the access token for a single Dropbox account instead of having each user connect their own account, but note that this is not recommended.